# Filling a missing value in a pandas data frame with an if statement based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, apply

I have this Pandas data frame in which some values are missing. For example, in row 542 the value of LATITUDE is missing. My goal is based on the condition CNTY_CITY_LOC to fill the missing value of LATITUDE by applying if elif and apply function in Pandas.
After I apply the if statement with the apply function of Pandas, the missing value is replaced but all other values in the LATITUDE column are missing. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help

[Missing values in column LATITUDE row 542](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urBBP.jpg)

[IF statement apply function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhLRX.jpg)

[Missing values in column Latitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJfUW.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary return value if no match, here `NaN` and for repalce only missing values in `CA_LOCATION['LATITUDE']` use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
def CA_LATITUDE(county_CODE):
    if county_CODE == 4710:
       return 41.5188
    else:
       return np.nan

CA_LOCATION['LATITUDE'] = CA_LOCATION['LATITUDE'].fillna(CA_LOCATION.CNTY_CITY_LOC.apply(CA_LATITUDE))
```

Better is use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with mapping by dictionary:

```
d= {4710:41.5188, 4711:41.5288...}
CA_LOCATION['LATITUDE'] = CA_LOCATION['LATITUDE'].fillna(CA_LOCATION.CNTY_CITY_LOC.map(d))
```

Comment: Why is it better to use  Series.fillna with mapping by dictionary?

Comment: @DANILOS - Because not necessary use function with many `if`, `elif` if need replace many values.